# wbraganca yii2-dynamicform with ckeditor and DateTimePicker

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I am using dynamic form for yii2 as described here 
https://github.com/wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform

Every thing is working fine, but ckeditor and date widget are working only for the first form, in the second form etc it shows simple textarea without ckeditor.Same to date widget from 2amigos. 
How can I fix this, so ckeditor and date could work in each added form?

**Update**

```
 <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     // Update fields with datepicker 
            function reInitDatepicker(){ 
            $('.datepicker-field').datepicker(); 
            } 
            // Dynamic form event 
   $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert",function(e,item)  {          
 alert('fff');
 reInitDatepicker(); 
       }); 
    }); 
</script>



<div class="clone">
 <div class="panel-body">
        <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
```

... etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ckeditor and datepicker instances after you add a new field. For example you may create function

```
// Update fields with datepicker
function reInitDatepicker(){
  $('.datepicker-field').datepicker();
}

// Dynamic form event
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    reInitDatepicker();
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain where can I place it? I tried to create new js file and place it there, but it did not work. I also tried to add this code above my form  and even alert didn't work   <script>
// Update fields with datepicker
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function reInitDatepicker(){
  $('.datepicker-field').datepicker();
}

// Dynamic form event
$(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
 alert('fff');
    reInitDatepicker();
});
});
</script>

Comment: Update your post with view code or where you run it all. @Jane08

Comment: Do you have errors in browser console? According to doc your code looks right.

Comment: No, I don't have errors or warning in browser console.

Comment: Try to create a clean page with example from github, click to add row and check whether `afterInsert` event will be fired.

Comment: by the way, alert is not working   (function ($) {
alert('fff');});   Maybe I use jQuery  not correctly in the context of Yii2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86711/discussion-between-jane08-and-size).